# Key Listener not working

Tags: java, applet, keylistener, event-listener

```
 public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    bufferGraphics.setColor (Color.black);
    bufferGraphics.clearRect (0, 0, dim.width, dim.width);
    while (input != KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        bufferGraphics.fillRect (0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
    }

    bufferGraphics.drawImage (track, 0, 0, dim.width, dim.height, this);
    bufferGraphics.setFont (new Font ("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    bufferGraphics.drawString ("Level: " + level, 30, 30);
    bufferGraphics.drawImage (car, 620, myCarY, 70, 120, this);
    bufferGraphics.drawImage (opponent, 415, oppCarY, 70, 120, this);
    move ();
```

This is the code as it stands now.  When executed, I get a frozen blank window that cannot even be closed.

Comment: Was it your intention to assign the value of "false" to "run"?

Comment: yes, and im a beginner, sorry

Comment: Just try:  while (!run) { ...}  The statement "run = false" is assigning the value of "false" to "run".

Comment: Why does your keyReleased assign Unicode null? Try making it `e.getChar()` like the others, unless there's a specific reason.

Comment: If this is done ,the program gets stuck in the for loop

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in your if statement.

```
if(run = false)
```

will never execute, as assignment returns the value being assigned (e.g. false).

You need to change your `=` to an `==`.

You may also want to change your infinite for loop to a while loop, something like

```
while(input != KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
}
```

Also make sure that your KeyListener is being added to your class (in ctor)

`addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener())`

I just tested the code, and it worked.

Comment: if this is done then the program gets stuck in that endless for loop and will never break when the space bar is pressed

Comment: I'm a beginner and not familiar with Frame/JFrame.  The KeyListener is just a seperate class at the bottom of my code

Comment: @KyleWilson Not much more I can do, just tested the code and it worked.

Comment: hmm no changes and it worked? all i get is a frozen white window